# Binding Multiple Parameters in an HTTP POST Request in ASP.NET Core .NET 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm encountering a challenge while migrating from ASP.NET MVC "classic" to ASP.NET Core with .NET 6.

In the past (ASP.Net MCV 4, ... 5), I could easily handle multiple parameters in an HTTP POST request, like this:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(MyComplexModel MyModel, bool isCompliant)
```

However, with ASP.Net Core (.Net 6.0), I'm facing difficulties in handling multiple parameters in the method signature. I've tried various solutions, including optional parameters, but so far, I haven't been able to achieve parameter binding as I expected.

My main issue is that I have a complex object, for example, MyComplexModel, and I'd like to pass a boolean parameter isCompliant without modify the model or having to create a new ViewModel or use a wrapper for every possible combination of parameters. It seems absurd to have to generate a different ViewModel each time just to change the number and types of aggregated data. Furthermore, in the "classic" MVC approach, it was sufficient for the parameters sent via JSON to match in number and type with those in the method signature, and the variables were automatically populated with the correct casts.

Currently, I've resolved the situation by using a single ViewModel that can handle various parameter combinations. Here's an example of how I manage it:

```
public class MyUnifiedViewModel
{
public MyComplexModel MyModel { get; set; }
public bool IsCompliant { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
 public IActionResult MyAction([FromBody] MyUnifiedViewModel viewModel)
 {
    // Now, I can access viewModel.MyModel and viewModel.IsCompliant
    // ...

   return Ok("Operation completed successfully.");
  }
```

I'm seeking your assistance and advice on how to tackle this situation more efficiently in ASP.NetCore 6, avoiding the creation of specific ViewModels for every possible parameter combination. What are the best practices or recommended approaches for handling multiple parameters in ASP.Net Core?

Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: if you have different endpoints reacting to different request data, you're gonna have different request models, I don't feel like you're making any sense with the premise of the question. Also im not sure if you can do this with FromBody, but the following works for query data: `[FromQuery] ManagementReportRequest req, [FromQuery] Guid category = default` which i suppose is what you want. ofc. This is the same as creating a parent request model with that field....

Answer (score 1):

If you send the isCompliant together with other property in json

you may need a custom model binder :

```
public class MyBinder : IModelBinder
 {
     public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
     {
         var modelName = bindingContext.FieldName;
         var body = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Body;
         body.Position = 0;
         using StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(body, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true);
         var str=reader.ReadToEnd();
         JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(str);
         var existproperty=jsonObject.TryGetValue(modelName, out var val);
         if (existproperty)
         {  
             //you have to modify the codes here,I would modify the codes here when I have free time
             var result=val?.ToString()=="True"?true:false;
             bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(result);
         }
         return Task.CompletedTask;
     }
 }
```

Enable request body be read mutiple times before first read(in my case,I tried with a middleware)

```
app.Use(async (httpcontext, next) =>
{
    httpcontext.Request.EnableBuffering();
    await next.Invoke();
});
```

apply the binder:

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(MyBinder))]bool? IsCompliant
```

Now it was bind successfully:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the point of your answer.... seems to me a more complex solution than creating a unique viewModel that handles the request.

Anyway, I tested your code.
isCompliant is true but the myComplexModel object is not initialized (it has id to 0 and properties to null)

I send the request as a simple post via ajax.

 `code`var requestBody = {
                        myComplexModel: { Id: 1, Prop1: 'theprop1', Prop2: 'theprop2' },
                        isCompliant: true  
                    };body: JSON.stringify(requestBody);`code`

Comment: Hi,@treep,I tried with the data:  {  Id: 1, Prop1: 'theprop1', Prop2: 'theprop2' , isCompliant: true }

Comment: If you want send data in your formatter,you would need two custom  binder,The default binder would read the json string from requestbody and directly deserialized  it to target object(MyComplexModel).The request body could be read  only once by default,that's why you couldn't read the bool value from request body again

Comment: My solution is for the scenaior that you want to keep the front end codes when you migrate your project to .net 6.If you would accept modify codes in your frontend ,just try as others suggeted,add the bool value to  query part

Comment: If you want  to try with the solution that keep the parameters in your action and the codes in frontend ,just create two custom binder,I would update the binder tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is use `[FromQuery]` before `isCompliant`

Next for route just use `asp-route-isCompliant` tag helper like this

```html
<form method="post" asp-contoller="MyController" asp-action="MyAction" asp-route-isCompliant="true">

</form>
```

**Note :** if you fill `isCompliant` parameter in form you can use `javascript` to change `form` `action`

Comment: I use post via ajax in my views to send data... but the point remains: does it seem normal that in ASP.Net Core sending a request with 2 or 3 parameters requires an action that accepts the same parameters in a single object? Methods that accept different numbers of parameters with different types will require new viewModels ... sounds ridiculous to me.

Comment: You are right but in this case we have two way and those remove problem. As my friend talk, if work it don't touch it @treep