# Passing guid and object to postman throwing syntax error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, postman, webapi

My Web API controller has the following method:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("updateUser")]
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateUser([FromBody] Guid userId, UserRequest request)
```

In Postman, I am trying to call request like this in body but it's throwing a syntax error

```
"27ab0d5a-4330-413c-bce1-21238dce44cb",
{    
  "name": "regex2",
  "city": "sdsdsdssd"
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: It's your json syntax that is the problem. You don't have an identifier in front of your GUID.

Comment: @MikeBruno i even tried having "id": "27ab0d5a-4330-413c-bce1-21238dce44cb"

Comment: Try `userId` since that's the identifier you're using in your method.

Comment: @MikeBruno sorry i meant "userId": "27ab0d5a-4330-413c-bce1-21238dce44cb"

Comment: Are you able to include the `Guid` and `UserRequest` and parameters in a single DTO class? That might make it easier because you could combine everything into a single json expression.  Your `UpdateUser` method would then take just one parameter `[FromBody]` of that DTO type.

Comment: @MikeBruno is it limitation that you can have only one FromBody parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to include the `Guid` and `UserRequest` and parameters in a single DTO class? That might make it easier because you could combine everything into a single json expression. Your UpdateUser method would then take just one parameter `[FromBody]` of that DTO type.

The DTO class would look like this:

```cs
class UpdateUserDto {
    public Guid userId {get; set;}
    public UserRequest userRequest {get; set;} = new();
}
```

And the signature of your POST message would change to this:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("updateUser")]
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateUser([FromBody] UpdateUserDto dto)
```

...And you would pass the serialized DTO into Postman like this:

```json
{
    "userId": "27ab0d5a-4330-413c-bce1-21238dce44cb",
    "userRequest":
    {
        "name": "regex2",
        "city": "sdsdsdssd"
    }
}
```

Comment: this i already know. My question is diferent

Comment: @james: If you "already know" this, why doesn't your "different" question include correctly formatted JSON as this answer does. The JSON you show in your question isn't close to being correctly formatted

Answer (score 0):

For controllers with `[ApiController]` attribute in default WebApi project,it would bind value from request body as if `[FromBody]` attribute is attached to your parameter

Also,Please check the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#frombody-attribute) related:

> Don't apply [FromBody] to more than one parameter per action method.
> Once the request stream is read by an input formatter, it's no longer
> available to be read again for binding other [FromBody] parameters.

If you want to seperate the parameters,you may try pass userid through query part,and modify your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("updateUser")]
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateUser([FromQuery] Guid userId, UserRequest request)
```

Here's a related [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77401542/binding-multiple-parameters-in-an-http-post-request-in-asp-net-core-net-6/77401870#77401870) you may check for detailed reason and another solution(not recommaned)